# Electorate badge percentage progress when a user has not cast any votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, electorate-badge, badge-progress

I just created an account on a site (I hadn't cast any votes yet), chose Electorate as the next badge on my profile and got the following:

[image: -2147483648/25 percent on questions]

It's still there. I tested on other sites (where I have not voted so far) and got the same discouraging percentage progress *(-2147483648/25 percent on questions)*. From a mathematical point of view there's no clear answer which percentage should be shown (it would be 0/0); perhaps it's better to replace the text by `You have not cast any votes` - the same message as in the votes tab:
[image: No votes cast]

Comment: Well it does make sense why it's -2147483648: it's a 32 bit signed int! That said, definitely a bug :)

Comment: Mhlester is right. Also, don't be discouraged! After you cast a single vote, the percent will look a little more relieving...

Comment: Reproduced on Super User with an account created 3 months ago (without casting any votes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, this was due to a divide by zero and some casting of the results.

Turns out that casting `NaN` to an `Int32` results in -2147483648.

Fixed in the next build.